# Getting Ticks on Axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've been struggling to get tick on Y axis, yet for some reason they dont appear on the plot. To be more precise, I'm using Subplot1.tick_params(axis='y', direction='out', length=5, width=3, colors='grey') to get tick marks on Y. Could somebody take a quick peek the code below and shed some light on this please. Many thanks in advance!

```
plt.style.use('seaborn-notebook')
Figure1 = plt.figure('testplot', figsize=(5,4), dpi=300)
Subplot1 = Figure1.add_subplot(1,1,1)

n = np.random.rand(45)
Subplot1.plot(n,np.sin(n))

Subplot1.spines['left'].set_color('k')
Subplot1.tick_params(axis='y', direction='out', length=5, width=3, colors='grey')
Subplot1.set_facecolor('white')
Figure1.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.13, left=0.13, top=0.82, right=0.92,  wspace=0.2, hspace=0.2)
Figure1.savefig('testplot' + '.tiff', dpi=300)`
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/H2HpSvO So what is wrong in here?

Comment: The code seems to work fine. You may want to show a picture of the output and use it to explain what's undesired about it. Also, mentionning the versions of the libraries in use would probably help.

Comment: Many thanks for replying to my query. I started commenting things out one at a time and eventually found out where glitch lies. Prior to this code section, I had included `sns.set() ` at the top of code. Even though had commented out this line of code, ticks failed to appear until the Python IDE was thoroughly closed and IDE restarted. For that reason, commenting out `sns.set() ` didnt get me ticks and gave me trouble figuring out what's wrong in here. Could you elaborate a bit on how come  `sns.set() ` caused this glitch as well as why this glitch didnt get fixed without having to close IDE?